# Error handling using child_process.execSync in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process, stderr

This is my NodeJs snippet:

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
  testoutput = execSync('make test');
```

Here I am getting *stdout* as output to *testoutput* variable from the execSync process if the make process is completely exited. But, if the *make test* process encounters an *stderr* error then I am getting an error in NodeJs.

How can I store the *stderr* message to an output variable *testoutput* if the make process does not exit and store *stdout* in variable *testoutput* if the process exits well with *stdout* output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To catch errors with `execSync()`, you need a `try/catch` around your call as errors will throw an exception.

Comment: This worked:   try {
  testoutput = execSync('make test');
  }
  catch (err){ 
    testoutput = err.stderr.toString()
  }

Comment: Note that if you run your project in a different operating system, there's a chance that certain commands may not fail but simply function differently. You may want to consider and handle those situations.